# Friend list chat with chatjs.net SignalR MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chat, signalr, chatjs

I started to implement a web chat system by using [chatjs.net](http://chatjs.net). But i wonder the friend list should bind the chat list. i refer the room chat with ROOM_ID_STUB is username logged.  But the friends list in my case will show online and offline user, unlike all sample chatjs.net will only is single room.

Can anyone suggest me the proper way to bind my friend list, and with each user logged will have a chat room and them share room chat list together ??

```
public class ChatHub : Hub, IChatHub
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This STUB. In a normal situation, there would be multiple rooms and the user room would have to be 
        /// determined by the user profile
        /// </summary>
        public const string ROOM_ID_STUB = "chatjs-room";

        /// <summary>
        /// Current connections
        /// 1 room has many users that have many connections (2 open browsers from the same user represents 2 connections)
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>> connections = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// This is STUB. This will SIMULATE a database of chat messages
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly List<DbChatMessageStub> dbChatMessagesStub = new List<DbChatMessageStub>();

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is STUB. This will SIMULATE a database of users
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly List<DbUserStub> dbUsersStub = new List<DbUserStub>();

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is STUB. In a normal situation, the user info would come from the database so this method wouldn't be necessary.
        /// It's only necessary because this class is simulating the database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newUser"></param>
        public static void RegisterNewUser(DbUserStub newUser)
        {
            if (newUser == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("newUser");
            dbUsersStub.Add(newUser);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is STUB. Returns if a user is registered in the FAKE DB.
        /// Normally this wouldn't be necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="user"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsUserRegisteredInDbUsersStub(DbUserStub user)
        {
            return dbUsersStub.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to find a user with the provided e-mail
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="email"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DbUserStub FindUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            if (email == null) return null;
            return dbUsersStub.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// If the specified user is connected, return information about the user
        /// </summary>
        public ChatUser GetUserInfo(int userId)
        {
            var user = dbUsersStub.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
            return user == null ? null : GetChatUserFromDbUserId(userId);
        }

        private ChatUser GetChatUserFromDbUserId(int dbUserId)
        {
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();

            // this is STUB. Normally you would go to the database get the real user
            var dbUser = dbUsersStub.First(u => u.Id == dbUserId);

            ChatUser.StatusType userStatus;
            lock (connections)
            {
                userStatus = connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId)
                                 ? (connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(dbUser.Id)
                                        ? ChatUser.StatusType.Online
                                        : ChatUser.StatusType.Offline)
                                 : ChatUser.StatusType.Offline;
            }
            return new ChatUser()
            {
                Id = dbUser.Id,
                Name = dbUser.FullName,
                Status = userStatus,
                ProfilePictureUrl = GravatarHelper.GetGravatarUrl(GravatarHelper.GetGravatarHash(dbUser.Email), GravatarHelper.Size.s32)
            };
        }

        private ChatMessage GetChatMessage(DbChatMessageStub chatMessage, string clientGuid)
        {
            return new ChatMessage()
            {
                Message = chatMessage.Message,
                UserFrom = this.GetChatUserFromDbUserId(chatMessage.UserFromId),
                UserTo = this.GetChatUserFromDbUserId(chatMessage.UserToId),
                ClientGuid = clientGuid
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns my user id
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private int GetMyUserId()
        {
            // This would normally be done like this:
            //var userPrincipal = this.Context.User as AuthenticatedPrincipal;
            //if (userPrincipal == null)
            //    throw new NotAuthorizedException();

            //var userData = userPrincipal.Profile;
            //return userData.Id;

            // But for this example, it will get my user from the cookie
            return ChatCookieHelperStub.GetDbUserFromCookie(this.Context.Request).Id;
        }

        private string GetMyRoomId()
        {
            // This would normally be done like this:
            //var userPrincipal = this.Context.User as AuthenticatedPrincipal;
            //if (userPrincipal == null)
            //    throw new NotAuthorizedException();

            //var userData = userPrincipal.Profile;
            //return userData.MyTenancyIdentifier;

            // But for this example, it will always return "chatjs-room", because we have only one room.
            return ROOM_ID_STUB;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Broadcasts to all users in the same room the new users list
        /// </summary>
        private void BroadcastUsersList()
        {
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();
            var connectionIds = new List<string>();
            lock (connections)
            {
                if (connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId))
                    connectionIds = connections[myRoomId].Keys.SelectMany(userId => connections[myRoomId][userId]).ToList();
            }

            // gets the current room user's list

            // this is STUB. You would normally go to the database to get the real room users
            var dbRoomUsers = dbUsersStub.Where(u => u.TenancyId == myRoomId).OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList();
            var usersList = dbRoomUsers.Select(u => this.GetChatUserFromDbUserId(u.Id)).ToList();

            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                this.Clients.Client(connectionId).usersListChanged(usersList);
        }

        private DbChatMessageStub PersistMessage(int otherUserId, string message)
        {
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();

            // this is STUB. Normally you would go to the real database to get the my user and the other user
            var myUser = dbUsersStub.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == myUserId);
            var otherUser = dbUsersStub.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == otherUserId);

            if (myUser == null || otherUser == null)
                return null;

            var dbChatMessage = new DbChatMessageStub()
            {
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Message = message,
                UserFromId = myUserId,
                UserToId = otherUserId,
                TenancyId = myUser.TenancyId
            };

            // this is STUB. Normally you would add the dbMessage to the real database
            dbChatMessagesStub.Add(dbChatMessage);

            // normally you would save the database changes
            //this.db.SaveChanges();

            return dbChatMessage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the message history
        /// </summary>
        public List<ChatMessage> GetMessageHistory(int otherUserId)
        {
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();
            // this is STUB. Normally you would go to the real database to get the messages
            var dbMessages = dbChatMessagesStub
                               .Where(
                                   m =>
                                   (m.UserToId == myUserId && m.UserFromId == otherUserId) ||
                                   (m.UserToId == otherUserId && m.UserFromId == myUserId))
                               .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).Take(30).ToList();

            dbMessages.Reverse();
            return dbMessages.Select(m => this.GetChatMessage(m, null)).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a message to a particular user
        /// </summary>
        public void SendMessage(int otherUserId, string message, string clientGuid)
        {
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();


            var dbChatMessage = PersistMessage(otherUserId, message);
            var connectionIds = new List<string>();
            lock (connections)
            {
                if (connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(otherUserId))
                    connectionIds.AddRange(connections[myRoomId][otherUserId]);
                if (connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(myUserId))
                    connectionIds.AddRange(connections[myRoomId][myUserId]);
            }
            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                this.Clients.Client(connectionId).sendMessage(this.GetChatMessage(dbChatMessage, clientGuid));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a typing signal to a particular user
        /// </summary>
        public void SendTypingSignal(int otherUserId)
        {
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();

            var connectionIds = new List<string>();
            lock (connections)
            {
                if (connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(otherUserId))
                    connectionIds.AddRange(connections[myRoomId][otherUserId]);
            }
            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                this.Clients.Client(connectionId).sendTypingSignal(this.GetUserInfo(myUserId));
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();

            lock (connections)
            {
                if (!connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId))
                    connections[myRoomId] = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

                if (!connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(myUserId))
                    connections[myRoomId][myUserId] = new List<string>();

                connections[myRoomId][myUserId].Add(this.Context.ConnectionId);
            }

            this.BroadcastUsersList();

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();
            var myUserId = this.GetMyUserId();

            lock (connections)
            {
                if (connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId))
                    if (connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(myUserId))
                        if (connections[myRoomId][myUserId].Contains(this.Context.ConnectionId))
                        {
                            connections[myRoomId][myUserId].Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId);
                            if (!connections[myRoomId][myUserId].Any())
                            {
                                connections[myRoomId].Remove(myUserId);
                                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                    {
                                        // this will run in separate thread.
                                        // If the user is away for more than 10 seconds it will be removed from 
                                        // the room.
                                        // In a normal situation this wouldn't be done because normally the users in a
                                        // chat room are fixed, like when you have 1 chat room for each tenancy
                                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                                        if (!connections[myRoomId].ContainsKey(myUserId))
                                        {
                                            var myDbUser = dbUsersStub.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == myUserId);
                                            if (myDbUser != null)
                                            {
                                                dbUsersStub.Remove(myDbUser);
                                                this.BroadcastUsersList();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            }
                        }
            }

            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @My.LamYahoo did you manage to achieve your goal? I want to implement the same behavior using friends list but facing the same problem.

Comment: @PiotrPtak - I solved it, in the method BroadcastUsersList(), var usersList = your friends list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void BroadcastUsersList()
        {
            var myRoomId = this.GetMyRoomId();
            var connectionIds = new List<string>();
            lock (connections)
            {
                if (connections.ContainsKey(myRoomId))
                    connectionIds = connections[myRoomId].Keys.SelectMany(userId => connections[myRoomId][userId]).ToList();
            }


            List<UserSite> dbRoomUsers = new List<UserSite>();
            int myId = GetMyUserId();
            List<Int>listFriendId = getListUserIdFriendOfUser(myId);
            listFriendId.Add(myId);
            foreach (var item in dbUsersStub)
            {
                if (listFriendId.Contains(item.Id))
                    dbRoomUsers.Add(item);
            }
            var usersList = dbRoomUsers.Select(u => this.GetChatUserFromDbUserId(u.Id)).ToList();

            foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                this.Clients.Client(connectionId).usersListChanged(usersList);
        }
```